# How to Match Clothes Rig to Follow Character Mesh Movement (Blender 2,7)

Tags: rigging

I tried to animate character with clothes but the problem is the clothes won't follow up the body movement. Like for example, when i wanted to bend the knees, the trouser can't bend like the knees do. Here's link to my blend file if anyone can help with it: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fu9UDFFM2cGUHXtMYyaBrbIhs4Ec6mXF/view?usp=sharing

Also, if there is a good video tutorial about it please tell me. I'm just started using blender and didn't know much of how to use it.

Comment: to begin with, the clorhes have not beed parented to the armature, so it can't follow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Side note: Consider upgrading to Blender 2.83 LTS if your hardware fulfills the requirements. The UI was redesigned in the update 2.79/2.80, also some shortcuts have changed. The shortcuts mentioned here are for 2.8+

First, you need to parent the cloth to the rig as you did with the body mesh with *Automatic Weights*. Then it will deform but there are still some issues.

### The Shirt

It has a different, not ideal topology. There are some loose & duplicated verts. The different topology will cause a lack of volume in the shoulders.

[image: orignal shirt]

You need to fix it (delete one side, fix the verts, and apply a *Mirror* modifier).  Or create it from the scratch. A common technique is to select the faces of the body mesh, duplicate them and separate these faces to a new object. Then scale up the shirt a bit and inflate/widen it. This way the topology fits the body's topology.

Add a *Soldify* modifier if you like but make sure the *Armature* modifier is on top of the stack.

[image: shirt version 2]

### Skin is sticking through the cloth

As you can see there is still some skin sticking through the cloth especially when the *Subdivision Surface* modifier is active and the mesh is deformed by the *Armature* modifier.

To prevent this you can do manually correct the weight paint and mask out the body mesh with the *Mask* modifier. Select the faces that you want to hide and assign them to a vertex group. Then add a *Mask* modifier, specify the vertex group and click the *Invert* <kbd><-></kbd> button.

[image: mask modifier]

### How to fix knee bending

To get a better bending of the knees you need to add a bit more geometry to the legs. If you have a look at the elbows you will notice that they have 2 extra edge loops.

The simplest method to get a better deformation is to add 2 more edge loops. For a better result, you want to give the kneecap more geometry and the back of the knee less so it can compress better. There are several methods to do this. Here are two for a low-poly mesh as your model has:

**Variant A**: Add two edge loops, create 2 triangles at the sides with the knife tool <kbd>K</kbd> and <kbd>X</kbd>, *Dissolve Edge*:

[image: variant a]
<sup>Variant A with Subdivision Surface level 1</sup>

[image: variant a mesh]

**Variant B**: Similar to A but insect <kbd>I</kbd> the front face to add a knee patch.
[image: variant b]
<sup>Variant B with Subdivision Surface level 1</sup>

[image: variant b mesh]